# Pass value to controller from post-method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{        
    <h3 class="text-blue title-article editable">thisStr</h3>

    <input type="submit" value="xxxx" class="btn btn-success" name="xxxx"/>
}
```

@model.title is part of an inline-editable that i can change to whatever, what i need to do is
pass the string in the h3 to this controller-method:

```
 public ActionResult method(string test)
        {   
            someProp = test;

            return View();
        }
```

I think my problem is this line:

```
<input type="submit" value="xxxx" class="btn btn-success" name="xxxx"/>
```

Can someone help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Title)
```

view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction","YourController",FormMethod.Post))
{        
    <h3 class="text-blue title-article editable">@Model.Title</h3>

     @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Title)

    <input type="submit" value="xxxx" class="btn btn-success" name="xxxx"/>
}
```

in your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(FormCollection form)
        {   
            sting vl= form["Title"].ToString();

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Ehsan! I think the problem has to do with my inline-editor, 
when i follow what you wrote, vl = an empty string. But your code works, cos the title in db show an empty string as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `@Html.HiddenFor((p) => Model.Title)` inside your form, which will then submit the text back with the POST for you.